Not sure if my proof is valid for Understanding Analysis by Abbots exercise 1.3.5 (a)
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Define the set $cA = \{ca: a \in A\}.$
(a) If $c \geq 0$, show that $\sup(cA) = c\sup(A)$.
This is my following proof: Since $A$ is bounded above, we can assume $\sup(A)$ exists. For $a \in A$, $\sup(A) \geq a$. Then, for $c\geq 0$, we can say $c\sup(A) \geq ca.$ We can also say that $\sup(cA) \geq ca$.
From here I concluded that $c\sup(A) = \sup(cA)$, but I'm not sure if the last step was valid. Can anyone help?

First, "we can assume $\sup A$ exists" is not an assumption. For your argument, all you've shown is that $c\sup A \geq \sup(cA)$.

Oh, I see, thank you for your response. Unfortunately I'm not sure where to continue from here.

Show $c\sup A \leq \sup(cA)$. Alternatively, choose $x_n\in A$ so that $x_n \to \sup A$. Then $cx_n \to c \sup A$. Since $c\sup A$ is an upper bound for $cA$, and there is a sequence of points in $cA$ which converge to $c\sup A$, it follows that $c\sup A = \sup(cA)$.

As a check: both the given answers are incomplete.  Do you see the case they both exclude?

Your last step is very wrong indeed. Let $$\alpha:=c\sup(A)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta:=\sup(cA).$$ From
$$(1)\quad\forall a\in A\quad\alpha\ge ca$$ and $$(2)\quad\forall a\in A\quad\beta\ge ca,$$ you cannot conclude $\alpha=\beta$.
However, note that $(1)$ is equivalent to $$\alpha\ge\beta.$$ For the reverse inequality, assuming wlog $c>0$, let $B:=cA$ (which is also nonempty and bounded above), and $d:=\frac1c$. Then, as we already proved, $d\sup(B)\ge\sup(dB)$, hence
$$\beta=\sup(B)\ge c\sup(dB)=\alpha.$$

Elegant and Short!

Let $M = \sup(A)$. We show that $cM = \sup(cA)$. As $M$ is the supremum of $A$, then $M \geq a, \forall a \in A$. Hence, $cM \geq ca, \forall a \in A$. If there were an $N$ such that $cM > N$ and $N$ were a an upper bound on $cA$, then $\frac{N}{c}$ would be an upper bound on $A$ and $M > \frac{N}{c}$ which is a contradiction of the definition of $M$. Hence, $cM$ is the least upper bound on $cA$.

For any $a\in A$, $a\le u\implies ca\le cu$ because $c\ge 0$.
Since $a\le \sup(A)$, for all $a\in A$, $ca\le c\sup(A)$, so $c\sup(A)$ is an upperbound for $cA$.
Suppose $u\lt c\sup{A}$
Then $\frac{u}{c}\lt\sup{A}$ so there exists $a\in A$ such that $$a\gt\frac{u}{c}\implies ca\gt u$$ Therefore, $u$ is not an upper bound for $cA$. Since this is true for all $u\lt c\sup{A}$, $c\sup{A}$ is the least upper bound of $cA$.
